# How many times more will the data in Datanode of Hadoop become by default compared to the original data?

Tags: hadoop

I have these four options and i dont know what will the answer
1. Twice 
2. Three Times
3. Four Times
4. 1.5 Times

Comment: Are you sure the question as stated is complete? Could you provide a context?

Comment: yeah, the question is complete.

Answer (score 0):

By default HDFS will have three replicas for each file block, so it will require three times the storage as the original data.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross check with the value seen in hdfs-site.xml

Search for:

```
<property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>3</value> 
</property>
```